# Uniform convergence of a certain series

Tags: real-analysis

I want to check the uniform convergence of $\sum (1-x)x^k$ and $\sum (1-x)^2x^k$ for $0 \leq x <1$

My attempt,  $\sum (1-x)x^k=(1-x)\sum x^k$ ,  $\sum (1-x)^2x=(1-x)^2\sum x^k$ and $\sum x^k $ is uniformly convergent for $0\leq x<1$, so both the series are uniformly convergent. Is it true?

Answer (score 1):

This won't work because $\sum x^k$ is not uniformly convergent, because as $x\to 1$ the speed of convergence falls. Also, even though $\sum x^k$ is not uniformly convergent this is not enough to conclude that $\sum (1-x)x^k$, as $1-x\to 0$ as $x\to 1$. However, $\sum (1-x)x^k$ is in fact not uniformly convergent, as it is uniformly convergent iff
$$\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^\infty (1-x)x^k = (1-x)\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)=x^{n+1}\to 0$$
uniformly, which is not true. I'll leave $\sum (1-x)^2x^k$ to you.

Comment: ahan! So i have to use Weirstrass M-Test?

Comment: No, if the series do not verify the M-test this do not imply that the series is not uniform convergent.

Comment: @Mathematician Not necessarily. You could simply note that its convergence is equivalent to $$\sum\limits_{i=n+1}^\infty (1-x)x^k = (1-x)\left(\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{1-x^{n+1}}{1-x}\right)=x^{n+1}\to 0$$ uniformly, which is not true.

Comment: @alexBecker the sequence is not uniformly convergent

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Whoops, fixing that.

Comment: Before you pass at limit, you must take the supremum of $x^{n+1}$ so the limit is equal 1.

Comment: @DominicMichaelis It happens. Sometimes I have a brain fart while wiriting an answer and the OP doesn't notice.

Answer (score 1):

Hint you know a formula for the geometric series, check if the new function is continuous in $1$ as it must be cause you have a sequence of continous functions

We can show it by using
$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$$ 
So $$(1-x)\sum_{k=0} x^k=\frac{1-x}{1-x}=1$$ 
when $x\neq 1$. For $x=1$ we have $f(x)=0$ so $f$ is not continuous in 1 and hence the the convergence can't be uniform.